# will this insert query take too long to run?

Tags: postgresql, node.js

I am bulk inserting from a node server to a psql database by constructing the query like

```
let query = `INSERT INTO ${table} (timestamp, lattitude, longitude, type) VALUES `;
locationData.forEach(location => {
    query += `('${location.timestamp}', '${location.lattitude}', '${location.longitude}', '${type}'), `;
});
```

this api gets called every 3 minutes by a device that logs location every second, meaning atmost 180 rows will be inserted in each query. will it be a bottleneck?

Comment: That's an average of 1 insert per second. Any decent hardware should be able to cope with that. Even my laptop could sustain that, probably even my smartphone.

Comment: Why is `${table}` a variable?

Comment: 180 narrow rows is *nothing* for modern Postgres on halfway modern hardware. No bottleneck at all. Over time, the size of the table may become an issue after adding 80k rows per day.

Comment: "Too long" is entirely subjective. Sorry, but the question's likely to be closed. You can edit it to be much more specific if you choose. The help section has a lot of guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said 180 rows is not a big deal.

That you are forming the 180 rows into a single insert command is a good thing, it will reduce both latency and the workload on the database.

Any computer capable of running Postgresql should have no problem with that work-load. this includes NAS boxes, cell-phones, and Raspberry Pis.